# Any clean way to avoid gstatic in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have the latest Laravel (8.5.9). I've noticed all my visitors will use gstatic (Google site for some caching), but I would like to avoid this behavior (I don't want to use any other web site or application than mine).

Gstatic is called by Illuminate (/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate) and also some fonts (/public/assets/fonts/google.css).

Please, do you have any clue to avoid this behavior ? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate` is a folder that holds the framework, how is that to "call gstatic"? `/public/assets/fonts/google.css` doesn't exist in a vanilla Laravel install. Do you have any packages installed? What hosting provider are you using? (Some might inject additional scripts/styles)

Comment: Thank you and you're right about font package installed, I will remove it easily.
I have a remote hosting and also a local installation with composer.

About Illuminate and the call of gstatic.com, I've noticed it with the NoScript plug-in which blocks it, even if I am on my local installation.